# Input number then keeps reading int. values until the sum of those integer equals or become greater than the value that was input in the beginning

Tags: java

I had tried this logic , but it is not working, please help me to resolve the issue

```
import java.util.Scanner ;  // USing  Scanner class 

class Check {

public static void main(String args[]){

 //Intializing & Declaring Variables 
 int num ;
 int sum ;
 int x = 1;
 // Creating object of Scanner Class 
 Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);

 while(x <= 100){

     System.out.println("Enter an Integer"); //Prompt
     num = input.nextInt(); // Taking input from User 

     sum = num + num ;
     x = sum;

 } // while lop ends

} // mainMethod ends
```

}// Class ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, prompt the user for a target value (instead of hardcoding `100`). Second, add `num` to `sum` (not `num` to `num`). Third, I would display the running total. Fourth, ***please*** prefer meaningful variable names. Something like,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// Prompt the user for a "target value"
System.out.println("Enter target value");
int target = input.nextInt();
// Initialize a running sum
int sum = 0;
// While the sum is less than or equal to the target value
while (sum <= target) {
    // Prompt the user for a value
    System.out.println("Enter an Integer");
    // Add the value to the sum
    sum += input.nextInt();
    // Display the current sum
    System.out.println("The current sum is " + sum);
}
// Indicate loop has completed
System.out.println("Done.");
```